Clean Ubuntu install reports enable-animations as false when they're enabled
Last week, I did a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 on a relatively beefy Thinkpad. This is going to be my Linux build machine (for a game I'm working on) so I installed only a few things: VSCode, Steam, Caffeine, Timeshift, and the requirements for building the game (Flutter SDK, development libraries).
While testing the game, I noticed that all animations in the game are skipped. I checked what the app thinks about the environment and it reports animations in the OS as disabled. I double-checked that they're not.

On the command line:
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/enable-animations
true

And also:
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations
true

I don't remember disabling animations in the OS. (And remember, I installed the OS last week and only use the laptop for a limited use case, so I'm inclined to believe my memory here.) It's also a beefy laptop, so I don't think the system is likely to disable animations automatically to save GPU resources, for example.
Yet, I get this:
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop --object-path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop --method org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations
(<<false>>,)

Apparently, this is where some applications are looking when trying to figure out whether animations are enabled.
Is this the wrong place for applications to look? Even if so, why does the last method give a different value than the other ones?
Update: Today I tried installing Ubuntu from scratch and I reproduced the issue, so it's not something I installed along the way. You can see my screenshot gallery here. This issue seems to not appear in installations of Ubuntu that were upgraded from version 22.04, only in clean installations of Ubuntu 24.04.
